# Como ficar escutando uma requisição no Angular 4

Tags: http-request, angular

Estou fazendo uma requisição Http no Angular 4, porém preciso ficar escutando a mesma e mostrando no template em tempo real, ou seja a medida em que for cadastrando as informações as mesmas aparecerem no grid automaticamente.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.userService.lista()
    .subscribe(data => {  this.usuarios = data });
}
```

esse e o retorno da requisição no componente pode me ajudar?

Comment: Isso daí é só quando ele inicia o template. Para adicionar conforme é inserido, você pode fazer pelo front ou, no método `save` da sua aplicação, o retorno dela você dar um push em usuários por exemplo. Pra responder com maior precisão, precisaria de mais detalhes...

Answer (score 0):

Cria um atributo na página para fazer o property bind:

```js
@Input() meuAtributo: any;// o tipo você que define

this.userService.lista()
    .subscribe( (data: any) => {
       this.meuAtributo = data;
        console.log(this.meuAtributo, data);
    });
```

```html
<h2 [(ngModel)]="meuAtributo"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, pode utilizar um interval

```
atualizarDados(){
  this.userService.lista()
 .subscribe(data => {  this.usuarios = data });
}

window.setInterval(atualizarDados, 600);
```

Isso vai fazer a cada 600 ms essa rotinha seja chamada ...